# How do I take Android Screen shots at the right size for publishing?

Tags: android

I'm sorry if this is a daft question but I appear to be missing something.

I am trying to publish my first app and I need at least 2 screen shots. I have taken these using DDMS in eclipse which produces an image 240 by 400. The market requires an image that is at least 320 by 480!

How do I generate a screenshot of this size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an AVD which has an HVGA skin/resolution. HVGA is by default 320x480. 
Run your application once more using this AVD and use DDMS to take screen shots.

Comment: really that simple?! never even thought of that! Will try

Answer (score 5):

Create an emulator from Eclipse with the required screen-size and run your app in the emulator and then use DDMS to take the screenshot.

From Eclipse: Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager. Create a New one. Specify a screen resolution of your desired size.